# javascript framework IE6 compatibility

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I want to determine the best javascript framework to use in order to maintain IE 6 compatibility.

Specifically I want to know which best supports IE6 - Dojo or JQuery.

I determine compatibility based on the amount of work you have to do to make the framework work with IE6 (framework may have features that need special coding to enable them to work with IE6, or there may be features that are incompatible altogether).

Are there any benchmarks, or compatibility matrices, for the various javascript frameworks that quantify the work you would have to do to maintain IE6 compatibility?

Comment: P.S. I could not find an existing question that addresses this issue, I'll close this question if someone can direct me to an existing answer.

Comment: All current mainstream frameworks are designed to support IE6 as the baseline browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both jQuery and DOJO claim they support IE6:

http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility

http://o.dojotoolkit.org/support/faq/what-browsers-does-dojo-support

DOJO does seem to have quite a grandiose claim:

> ... 100% of the available
>   functionality works, that
>   accessibility is handled correctly,
>   and that all internationalization and
>   localization is supported. This is a
>   *very* high bar, ...

And jQuery claims they test regularly in IE6.

Personally, I would let other requirements dictate which framework you use. One of the fundamental jobs for a JavaScript library is to be cross browser compatible, so any decent library is going to be good at it.

Comment: If the javascript can run in IE6, then it can run in any browser.

Answer (score 1):

"Better" in your question indicates subjectivity, so I'd probably change this to a community wiki.

The best thing to do in each case is to look at what the libraries say they support. I know that he following frameworks handle IE6 well:

- [**Prototype**](http://prototypejs.org)
- [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com)

I don't have up-to-date personal experience with [**Dojo**](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or [**ExtJS**](http://www.extjs.com/), but they supported IE6 well a couple of years back when I looked into them — I'd be surprised if they don't still support it (for now). (ExtJS's "[learn more](http://www.extjs.com/products/js/?ref=learnmorebluebutton)" page says IE6 and up; the "supported" list on the Dojo front page is not, shocking, a link to a list.)

The [**Closure**](http://code.google.com/closure/library) team originally said they supported IE6 (although they [have no official list](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/7291e569602415a8/c652d3590b8adede)), but that may have changed with Google's recent decision to drop IE6 support from their web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst other things, the main priority of a javascript library is to solve the cross-browser issues. Having said that, I personally use [**jQuery**](http://jquery.org) and yes it overcomes the IE6 issues too other than other later versions of IE.